# There is/are a lot of (uncountable noun) and many (countable noun)?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

I know that the title is a little bit clumsy, so let me explain further.

From basic grammatical rules, we know that we should use "is" when "a lot of" is followed by an uncountable noun.

For example:

> There is a lot of sugar in the container.

Also, we should use "are" with "many"

For example:

> There are many people over there.

Then I wonder what to use if both appear in a sentence.

For example:

> There _______ (be) a lot of fruit and many facilities in the museum.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the rule about uncountable nouns is not right and needs some expansion. Uncountable nouns can either be singular or plural in form. Examples of plural ones include jeans, pants, glasses (spectacles) and goods. They use are rather than is in your example.

For your question I would say "is" is the correct usage. In order to use "are" there needs to be some grouping of the two and "many" being applied to the former and not the latter breaks that.